# How can I retrieve the full directory tree using SPL?

Tags: php, spl

How can I retrieve the full directory tree using `SPL`, possibly using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` will use `LEAVES_ONLY` for the second argument to [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php). This means it will return files only. If you want to include files *and* directories (at least that's what I'd consider a *full* directory tree), you'd have to do:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

and then you can `foreach` over it. If you want to return the directory tree instead of outputting it, you can store it in an array, e.g.

```
foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
    $files[] = $fileObject;
    // or if you only want the filenames
    $files[] = $fileObject->getPathname();
}
```

You can also create the array of `$fileObjects` without the `foreach` by doing:

```
$files[] = iterator_to_array($iterator);
```

If you only want directories returned, `foreach` over the `$iterator` like this:

```
foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
    if ($fileObject->isDir()) {
        $files[] = $fileObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just, or do everythng that you want

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file)
{
    /* @var $file SplFileInfo */
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, what I don't understand is, how - from the PHP doc of [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) - do you deduct that `$file` is of type SplFileInfo ?