# is_dir doesn't recognize directories. Why?

Tags: php, directory, readdir

I have this function:

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
        //are we able to open it?
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            //Let's cycle
            while (($subdir = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($subdir != "." && $subdir != "..") {

                    echo $subdir;

                }
        }
}
```

This returns:

```
directory1 , directory2, directory3 etc.. etc..
```

Hoever if I do this:

```
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        //are we able to open it?
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            //Let's cycle
            while (($subdir = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($subdir != "." && $subdir != "..") {

                    if (is_dir($subdir)) { 
                       echo $subdir;
                    }

                }
        }
}
```

It doesn't print nothing!

Why does this happens?
I'm running the script withing windows and XAMPP for testing purposes. The directory does in fact contain directories.

Thank you

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418068/php-spl-recursivedirectoryiterator-recursiveiteratoriterator-retrieving-the-full/2655620#2655620

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`is_dir($dir . '/' . $subdir)`

Answer (score 4):

readdir() only gives the file/dir name and not the full path (which is_dir apparently needs).

Found here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php#79622

Answer (score 1):

Its because `$dir` is a full path where as `$subdir` is only a path fragment