# search files in directory using php

Tags: php, directory-structure

i have a situation,i am creating a folder everytime when new user register.the folder name is equal to username.so therefore user_data folder contains all folder which name is equal to username.
when user upload something then it directly save to its desired username folder.

so now i want to search perticular file from these folder. i know that, that particular file save in user_data folder but i dont know in user_data foder which folder contain that file.
so what will be the code for searching file in directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SPL RecursiveDirectoryIterator RecursiveIteratorIterator retrieving the full tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418068/php-spl-recursivedirectoryiterator-recursiveiteratoriterator-retrieving-the-full)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/de/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php)
combine it with `strstr` or `preg_match`

Comment: If the filename is known, there is no need for `strstr` or `preg_match`

Comment: yes your right if the filename (including extension) is known its only comparing strings (after `basename` on `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getSubPathName()`)

Answer (score 4):

`glob()` should do the trick. Here's an example of its usage. hope it helps:

```
$filenames = glob('user_data\\'. $username . '\\*.jpg');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    echo $filename ."\n";
}
```

Comment: But there's an issue when `$username` contains specially treated characters such as `*` and `?`, therefore using the `DirectoryIterator` class and its derivatives is IMO a more suited approach to the problem.