# How to reference the current directory name, filename and file contents with RecursiveDirectoryIterator loop?

Tags: php, spl, recursive-datastructures

In the script below, I'm attempting to iterate over the folders and files inside of the $base folder. I expect it to contain a single level of child folders, each containing a number of .txt files (and no subfolders).

I'm just needing to understand how to reference the elements in comments below...

Any help much appreciated. I'm really close to wrapping this up :-)

```
$base = dirname(__FILE__).'/widgets/';
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi) as $files_widgets) 
    {
     if ($files_widgets->isFile()) 
         {
            $file_name_widget = $files_widgets->getFilename(); //what is the filename of the current el?
            $widget_text = file_get_contents(???); //How do I reference the file here to obtain its contents?
            $sidebar_id = $files_widgets->getBasename(); //what is the file's parent directory name?
        }
    }
```

Comment: *(related)* [PHP SPL RecursiveDirectoryIterator RecursiveIteratorIterator retrieving the full tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418068/php-spl-recursivedirectoryiterator-recursiveiteratoriterator-retrieving-the-full/2655620#2655620)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//How do I reference the file here to obtain its contents?
    $widget_text = file_get_contents(???);
```

`$files_widgets` is a [SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), so you have a few options to get the contents of the file.

The easiest way is to use `file_get_contents`, just like you are now.  You can concatenate together the path and the filename:

```
$filename = $files_widgets->getPathname() . '/' . $files_widgets->getFilename();
$widget_text = file_get_contents($filename);
```

If you want to do something *funny*, you can also use [`openFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.openfile.php) to get a [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php).  Annoyingly, SplFileObject doesn't have a quick way to get all of the file contents, so we have to build a loop:

```
$fo = $files_widgets->openFile('r');
$widget_text = '';
foreach($fo as $line)
    $widget_text .= $line;
unset($fo);
```

This is a bit more verbose, as we have to loop over the SplFileObject to get the contents line-by-line.  While this is an option, it'll be easier for you just to use `file_get_contents`.

Comment: thanks. I just had to remove the 2nd part to become    $filename = $files_widgets->getPathname();

Comment: +1 Now I'm just left with obtaining the current directory name (aka the current file's parent). I can't see a method, do you?

Comment: Got it > $parentname = basename($files_widgets->getPath());